# Is there an API that retrieves a list of items for a given category?

Tags: json, get, wikipedia-api, google-custom-search

I figure since Google Sets used to exist and [somewhat still does](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2012/11/google-sets-still-available.html), there must exist some API (google or otherwise) where I could send a category as a GET request and retrieve a JSON listing of items in that category.

For example:

```
In: 'sports' 
Out: {'basketball', 'football', 'baseball', 'hockey', 'soccer', 'lacrosse', ...}

In: 'animals'
Out: {'dog', 'cat', 'fish', 'bird', 'horse', ...}
```

I'm thinking that the answer might have something to do with Google's custom search API, or perhaps even Wikipedia?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably an MQL query to freebase

http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/MQL

Something like [this for sports](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=%5B%7B%22name%22%3a%20null,%22id%22%3a%20null,%22type%22%3a%20%22/sports/sport%22,%22limit%22%3a%2025%7D%5D)